# Why is my specific selector not working with nth-of-type() and nth-child()?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am still a beginner and I can not find the mistake in my code. Your help would really be appreciated so I can learn the basics right.

I want to change the background of the class="post-content" in every even post to red.

It is not working. If I just change it in every post it is totally fine. But the moment I use the child or type selector it just applies it to both posts.

If I try to change the class="container" and then specify with the child or type selector it works on every even post. Why does it not function on the "post-content" class?

Html

```html
<div id="content">

     <div class="container">
       <div class="post">
         <div class="post-author">
           <img src="me.png" alt="picture of the author">
           <span>Me</span>
         </div>
         <p class="post-date">Today</p>
         <h3 class="post-title">Post1</h3>
         <div class="post-content">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
       <div class="post">
         <div class="post-author">
           <img src="Ahmad.png" alt="picture of the guest author">
           <span>Ahmad</span>
         </div>
         <p class="post-date">Today</p>
         <h3 class="post-title">Post2</h3>
         <div class="post-content">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
              cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
              proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container:nth-of-type(2n+0)  {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

`works (with child or type)`

.post-content {
  background-color: red;
}

`works as well, all posts are now red`

.post-content:nth-of-type(2n+0){
  background-color: red;
}

`does not work, both post backgrounds are still red (if I try the odd ones, none is red)`
```

Comment: You can simply pass even odd as well not nth-type for your particular situation :)

Comment: `.container:nth-of-type(even) .post-author { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

the `nth-of-type` pseudo selector is applied to a group of sibling elements [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). Since in your div with class `post` is only one element of the class `post-content`. This element is always on position `0` therefore `2n+0` (which could be just written as `2n` will match them.

To achieve what you want you should use: `.container:nth-of-type(2n) .post-content { ... }` as selector. This will first select every second div with the `container` class and then apply the stuff to the div with the `post-content` class in it. To learn more about CSS selectors, I'd recommend taking a look at https://flukeout.github.io/, you'll need to provide different selectors including nested to pass the levels.

**Explanation** *(run the snippet for a visual example)*

```css
.foo {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

.foo:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.foo .foo {
  margin-left: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo">
    Foo even (foo within .wrapper at index 0)
    <div class="foo">
      Foo even (foo within .foo, at index 0)
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
      Foo odd (foo within .foo, at index 1)
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
      Foo even (foo within .foo, at index 2)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Foo odd (foo within .wrapper at index 1)
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    Foo even (foo within .wrapper at index 2)
  </div>
</div>
```

What hapend in your case, was the nested example, since, all of your `.post-content` elements where the first element in their scope, they where always selected.

Comment: Ok so to recap, when I use 

.container:nth-of-type(2n) .post-content or
.container:nth-child(2n) .post-content 
it works because I specify the .container as the respective siblings and I then add .post-content to specify what in those siblings should be changed?

Because the .container are siblings under the <div id="content"> parent but the two <div class="post-content"> are simply not siblings to each other?

Thank your for your answer and the provided link!